# Angular version of a jQuery page

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm looking how can I create my first app. My knowledge is more jQuery and it's hard for me to make the switch.

Actually, my first page in JS would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" data-module="Module-1">Module 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-module="Module-2">Module 2</a>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#content').load('modules/homepage.html');

            $('a[data-module]').click(function(event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 var module = $(this).attr('data-module');
                 $('#content').load(module);
            });
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

But how can I make the same to switch my content ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of xhr requests and executing javascript on a click, you want to look at [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) respectively. But really, you have to start from the beginning because you need to understand the Angular way of doing things.

I would check the official tutorial documentation here:

[Angular Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-view or ui-view (i recommend ng-view) instead of jQuery, because both are optimized to create single page application, just need for example something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SPA</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

with ng-view you can change the views dinamically, here is a complete example more clear:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

I hope it will be useful for you, regards.